# Using values from one data file to select rows from another data file

Tags: r, csv, aggregate

I have data from multiple participants and I am trying to use information from one set of files to aggregate data in another set of files.

I have one data file (`videodata.csv`) with four columns: `Event.Type` (video name), `Name` (start or end), `Row` (row number), and `Source` (the participant id code). Set up like this:

```
videodata <- data.frame(
  Event.Type = c("Movie1", "Movie1", "Movie2", "Movie2", "Movie3", "Movie3",
                 "Movie1", "Movie1", "Movie2", "Movie2", "Movie3", "Movie3",
                 "Movie1", "Movie1", "Movie2", "Movie2", "Movie3", "Movie3"),
  Name = c("start", "end", "start", "end","start", "end",
           "start", "end", "start", "end","start", "end",
           "start", "end", "start", "end","start", "end"),
  Row = c(1, 10, 11, 20, 21, 30,
           8, 16, 19, 28, 1, 7,
           2, 8, 21, 26, 9, 20),
  Source = c("012", "012", "012", "012", "012", "012",
             "013", "013", "013", "013", "013", "013",
             "014", "014", "014", "014", "014", "014")
)
```

I have like 80 participants, so each of them have another data file in csv format (`id_data.csv`), with two columns: `time` and `score`. Each row corresponds to one second, so the `time` column is simply numbered from 1 to somewhere around 1,800 or whatever it goes to. `score` is a binary code of `0` or `1`.
For participants 012, 013, and 014 data would look like this:

```
`012_data` <- data.frame(
  time = c(1:30),
  score = c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
)

`013_data` <- data.frame(
  time = c(1:30),
  score = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
)

`014_data` <- data.frame(
  time = c(1:30),
  score = c(0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
)
```

I want to use the information from `videodata.csv` to slice up `id_data.csv` and save them into individual files corresponding to `Event.Type`.

Specifically, I would look in the `videodata.csv` file to find the id number. For a given id number, I would start with the first `Event.Type` (eg Movie1) and find the start `row` and end `row`. I would use this information to go to the data file for that id number and select those rows of `score` and save them to a file called `movie1.csv`. I would repeat for each participant until `movie1.csv` contained data from all participants.

For example, for participant 012, I would like to slice up the `id_data.csv` file into three chunks corresponding to Movie1, Movie2, and Movie3. To do this I would:

1. I would select rows 1-10 (based on `Row` which indicates the Start and End) by rounding up to the nearest row number
2. Save the `score` column to a file called Movie1 with the column header `012` from the `Source` column
3. Repeat for participant `013` and append their `score` column next to the previous row.
4. Then repeat for participants 014 and so on through 80.

The resulting file for `Movie1` might look like this:
[image]

It includes values of `score` from rows 1-10 (for 012) 8-16 (for 013) and 2-8 (for 014).

I would then have another file corresponding to Movie2 (by selecting rows 11-20, 19-28, and 21-26), and so on for each participant id.
Each participant might have a slightly different number of rows.

This is just beyond my skill and I would appreciate any help as to how I can accomplish this. Thanks!

Comment: Only r way, or is it possible to suggest some cli tool answer?

Comment: @aborruso only R please. It needs to fit into my existing work flow.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have your id data in a directory `data\id`, and that they all have the same 2 columns `time` and `score`, we can read them in all at once with `readr::read_csv()` while specifying the `id` argument which will save the file path as a column. We can then split that file path and keep just the part we want to get a `Source` column that matches the video data.

We can then join the data on the `Source` column, but only after pivoting both wide. With the data joined, we can then pivot them long and define a new `Event.Type` column by finding the time with the start and end parameters. Finally we select only the columns we want, and pivot them wider again to get the desired output.

This will still contain all the movies, but you can easily add a `dplyr::filter(Event.Type == "Movie1")` to get unique files.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(here)

# Here I take your dummy data and write them as csv's

`012_data` <- data.frame(
  time = c(1:30),
  score = c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
) %>% write_csv(here::here('data', 'id', '012_data.csv'))

`013_data` <- data.frame(
  time = c(1:30),
  score = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
) %>% write_csv(here::here('data', 'id', '013_data.csv'))

`014_data` <- data.frame(
  time = c(1:30),
  score = c(0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
) %>% write_csv(here::here('data', 'id', '014_data.csv'))

# Read them back in all at once into a single tibble

id_data <- here::here('data', 'id') %>% 
  list.files(full.names = T) %>% 
  readr::read_csv(id = 'Source') %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Source = stringr::str_split_i(Source, pattern = "\\/", i = -1),
                Source = stringr::str_remove(Source, pattern = "_data.csv")) %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = time, values_from = score)

videodata <- data.frame(
  Event.Type = c("Movie1", "Movie1", "Movie2", "Movie2", "Movie3", "Movie3",
                 "Movie1", "Movie1", "Movie2", "Movie2", "Movie3", "Movie3",
                 "Movie1", "Movie1", "Movie2", "Movie2", "Movie3", "Movie3"),
  Name = c("start", "end", "start", "end","start", "end",
           "start", "end", "start", "end","start", "end",
           "start", "end", "start", "end","start", "end"),
  Row = c(1, 10, 11, 20, 21, 30,
          8, 16, 19, 28, 1, 7,
          2, 8, 21, 26, 9, 20),
  Source = c("012", "012", "012", "012", "012", "012",
             "013", "013", "013", "013", "013", "013",
             "014", "014", "014", "014", "014", "014")
)  %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = c(Event.Type,Name), values_from = Row)

df <- dplyr::left_join(videodata, id_data) %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = 8:37, names_to = "time", values_to = "score") %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    time = as.numeric(time),
    Event.Type = dplyr::case_when(
      time >= Movie1_start & time <= Movie1_end ~ 'Movie1',
      time >= Movie2_start & time <= Movie2_end ~ 'Movie2',
      time >= Movie3_start & time <= Movie3_end ~ 'Movie3',
      T ~ as.character(NA)),
    score = ifelse(is.na(Event.Type), NA, score)) %>%
  dplyr::select(Event.Type, Source, score) %>% 
  tidyr::drop_na() %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Event.Type, Source) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = Source, values_from = score)

df
# A tibble: 32 × 5
# Groups:   Event.Type [3]
   Event.Type    id `012` `013` `014`
   <chr>      <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 Movie1         1     0     0     1
 2 Movie1         2     0     1     0
 3 Movie1         3     0     0     0
 4 Movie1         4     0     0     0
 5 Movie1         5     1     1     1
 6 Movie1         6     0     0     0
 7 Movie1         7     0     0     1
 8 Movie1         8     0     0    NA
 9 Movie1         9     1     1    NA
10 Movie1        10     0    NA    NA
# … with 22 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Update: My updated answer takes inspiration from @asd-tm. Their answer is overall better, but perhaps you could use bits from both such as file reading from me, and data cleanup from them.

Comment: If you have more than, say 10 movies... Your `case_when` is going to be very heavy to use...

Comment: Yeah, I also realized this, it's a bit quick and dirty. I am happy to edit the answer with any suggestions on how to solve this.

Comment: @Cullen.Molitor your resulting output has NAs at the top row. But the first row (line 1) should be the `score` from row 1 (for 012 data), row 8 (for 013 data) and row 2 (for 014 data). That is, the 'start' row should be the first row for any given Movie. Since each id would have varying lengths of rows, the NAs need to be appended at the end.

Comment: Updated my code to get you there, but @asd-tm has much cleaner logic overall.

Answer (score 1):

As I assume that the numer of rows in each of the _data.csv files might differ I would suppose to combine the data in the following way:

```
data_list <- list()
data_list[["012_data"]] <- `012_data`
data_list[["013_data"]] <- `013_data`
data_list[["014_data"]] <- `014_data`
```

I attract your attention that here is a list not a dataframe because of possible variations of data structure and row count. The same effect can be achieved while reading files in a `lapply` function applied to `list.files`.

Then we create the "long" data.frame with data from such files.

```
rm(dl)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

for (filename in names(data_list)) {
  if (exists("dl")) {
    dl <- dl %>% 
      union_all(
        data_list[[filename]] %>% 
          mutate(fileName = strsplit(filename, "_")[[1]][1]) # Here we use base R function
      )
  } else {
    dl <- data_list[[filename]] %>% 
      mutate(fileName = strsplit(filename, "_")[[1]][1])
  }
}
```

All these steps can be done at file upload.

`dl` is long and thus handy for further manipulations:

```
> dl
   time score fileName
1     1     0      012
2     2     0      012
3     3     0      012
4     4     0      012
5     5     1      012
...
```

All the rest is done in a single pipe:

```
videodata %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Name, values_from = Row) %>% 
  left_join(dl, by = c("Source" = "fileName")) %>% 
  filter(time >= start& time <= end) %>% 
  select(-c(start, end, time)) %>% 
  group_by(Event.Type, Source) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Source, values_from = score)
```

You can see the intermediate results executing the pipe stepwise. The pipe returns the following output:

```
# A tibble: 32 × 5
# Groups:   Event.Type [3]
   Event.Type    id `012` `013` `014`
   <chr>      <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 Movie1         1     0     0     1
 2 Movie1         2     0     1     0
 3 Movie1         3     0     0     0
 4 Movie1         4     0     0     0
 5 Movie1         5     1     1     1
 6 Movie1         6     0     0     0
 7 Movie1         7     0     0     1
 8 Movie1         8     0     0    NA
 9 Movie1         9     1     1    NA
10 Movie1        10     0    NA    NA
11 Movie2         1     0     0     0
12 Movie2         2     0     0     0
13 Movie2         3     0     0     0
14 Movie2         4     0     0     0
15 Movie2         5     0     0     0
16 Movie2         6     0     0     0
17 Movie2         7     0     0    NA
18 Movie2         8     0     0    NA
19 Movie2         9     0     0    NA
20 Movie2        10     0     0    NA
21 Movie3         1     0     0     0
22 Movie3         2     0     0     0
23 Movie3         3     0     0     0
24 Movie3         4     0     0     0
25 Movie3         5     0     0     0
26 Movie3         6     0     0     0
27 Movie3         7     0     0     0
28 Movie3         8     0    NA     0
29 Movie3         9     0    NA     0
30 Movie3        10     0    NA     0
31 Movie3        11    NA    NA     0
32 Movie3        12    NA    NA     0
```

The other advantage of this code is that it does not contain any references to movie names and thus scalable without modifications as in other answer. It is robust to differences in number of items selected (see number of elements in Movie1 == 10 and Movie3 == 12). It will also work propwerly if the number of elements for 012 is less then for rightwards columns 013, 014 etc

Answer (score 0):

I managed to generate the files as you wanted. Please check the comments in the code for a deeper explanation.

I think the last block (the double loop) may not be the most efficient solution in terms of time, but it is the "cleanest" I could come up with. Sometimes is better to sacrifice some performance for the sake of understandability.

```
### load necessary packages
library(data.table)

### read file from disk (I used your data)
videodata = fread("videodata.csv")
    
### read individual files from disk. If not exactly 80, adjust
### the number. If the filename pattern doesn't match exactly,
### adjust accordingly. (I used your data)

individualFileNames = paste(sprintf("%03d", 1:80), "data.csv", sep = "_")

### files are read into a **list**
individualData = lapply(individualFileNames, fread)

### we need this because of your naming convention :'(
### In general, it's bad idea to name files starting with a number
names(individualData) = paste(sprintf("%03d", 1:80), "_data", sep = "")
    
### a function to pad with NAs the vectors of different lengts
padNAs = function(x){
  n = max(sapply(x, length))
  for (i in 1 : length(x)){
    length(x[[i]])= n
  }
  as.data.table(x)
}

### This double loop will go over each event type (movie) and
### each source in it, and create a table of the scores (which
### are obtained from each individual data table). The table
### is then exported as a csv file with the name of the movie.

for (i in videodata[, unique(Event.Type)]){
  j_score = list()
  counter = 1
  for (j in videodata[, unique(Source)]){
    filename = paste0(i, ".csv")
    startRow = videodata[Event.Type == i & Source == j & Name == "start", Row]
    endRow = videodata[Event.Type == i & Source == j & Name == "end", Row]
    j_score[[counter]] = individualData[paste0(j, "_data")][[1]][startRow : endRow, score]
    names(j_score)[counter] = j
    counter = counter + 1
  }
  fwrite(padNAs(j_score), file = filename)
}
```

Comment: @socialresearcher did this solution work for you?

Comment: @socialresearcher did this solution work for you?